# How do I enable translation to other languages in Openstack Horizon?

Tags: openstack-horizon

I am tasked to enable different languages in Openstack Horizon.

I am working on a horizon page built on top of dev stack. The Horizon page is pulled from here: https://github.com/openstack/horizon.
I want to enable translation to different languages in Horizon.

I tried to follow this documentation: https://docs.openstack.org/horizon/latest/contributor/topics/translation.html

This is an example of my code, I am trying to translate this phrase: “*API Access*” found in the panel on the main page :
Before editing the code, I saw that there is a corresponding translated message in openstack_dashboard/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/django.po:

```
msgid "API Access"
msgstr "访问API"
```

This is what I did:

Firstly, In openstack_dashboard/dashboards/project/api_access/panel.py, I edited **name = _("API Access")** to **name=pgettext("API Access", "API Access")**:

```
from django.utils.translation import pgettext
import horizon

class ApiAccess(horizon.Panel):
     name = pgettext("API Access","API Access")
     slug = 'api_access'
```

Secondly, I ran **tox -e manage -- extract_messages** in the main openstack/horizon folder

Thirdly, I ran **tox -e manage -- update_catalog** in the main openstack/horizon folder

After I run it, this following keyword "API Access" is still not translated.
(i.e. I started horizon, went to settings, and change the language to zh-cn. But the word "API Access" is still in English.)

Not sure if this is helpful:
In openstack_dashboard/locale/Django.pot, I see this:

```
#: openstack_dashboard.dashboards/project/api_access/panel.py:22
msgctxt "API Access"
msgid "API Access"
msgstr ""
```

Grateful to anyone who can help me solve this translation issue.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I manage to fix it by switching to clean branch and just follow the documentation!